# How to add a Subtitle as default to a video already containing a subtitle stream using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

These are the two input files, I want to mux using ffmpeg.

**- input.mkv**

**- input.srt**

**'input.mkv'** has the following streams

- **Stream 0:0 video**
- **Stream 0:1 audio**
- **Stream 0:2 subtitle (ass)**
- **Stream 0:3 attachment ttf (font)**

I want all streams of **'input.mkv'** and also **'input.srt'** as default subtitle stream in  **'output.mkv'**

Note: I know I can use **'mkvmerge'** but I need **'ffmpeg'** commands.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i input.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:s:1 default output.mkv` See duple link for more examples.